# getting empty input on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to implement a search function, currently, I am implementing a single search field but there will be more in future.

The problem is when I submit the form to search the data it is submitting a null value as I can see in the result query.
and `console.log()` also printing **else block** even if I have input in the input field.
what is the issue, everything looks fine to me, anyone can point out the issue please?

**blade**

```
<form id="studSearchForm" autocomplete="off" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<div class="searchBox">
Search Student
<div class="searchContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="studfnameSearch" name="studfnameSearch" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="student first name">            
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">                    
                Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $("#studSearchForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fd = new FormData(this);
    var _url = '{{ route('student.fetch.route') }}';
    $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        method: 'GET',
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```

**web route**

```
Route::get('student-fetch', [StudentRegController::class, 'fetchStudent'])->name('student.fetch.route');
```

**controller**

```
public function fetchStudent(Request $request) {
    $fnameQuery = $request->input('studfnameSearch');    
    if (!empty($fnameQuery)) {
        $studSearch = DB::table('school_students')->where('student_first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$fnameQuery}%")
            ->get('student_first_name');
        return response()->json($studSearch);
    } else {
        return response()->json("empty search");

    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormData` is used to generate multipart form data request **bodies**.

It isn’t compatible with a GET request, which can’t have a request body and expects data to be placed in the query string.

Normally I would suggest using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to generate a query string, but I don’t know if jQuery is modern enough to support it. Consider jQuery [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, for sharing the knowledge, it worked fine.
don't know why blogs and tutorial using get method and claiming its working whereas not working in my case

Comment: I've never seen a recommendation to mix `FormData` and `GET` before. I've no idea what blog or tutorial you are reading that does.